# Has Cloud Foundry removed facility of adding environment variables in later versions of VMC?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am currently using VMC version 0.4.3 and it seems that the following command to add environment variables does not work in this version:

**vmc env-add {app-name} {key=value}**

This utility command worked for vmc version 0.3.14 and now I cannot use it on the latest version.

Get the following message on using this command: "**Unknown command 'env-add'. See 'help' for available commands.**"

It would be great if someone could shed more light on this matter please.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Thanks,

Kinjal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the more recent versions of VMC, the env commands have been changed to the following;

To view an apps environment variables

```
vmc env [application name]
```

To set an environment variable

```
vmc set-env [application name] key=value
```

To unset an environment variable

```
vmc unset-env [application name] key
```

We are currently working on updating the online documentation for the more recent versions of VMC.